# How to output to the application itself

Tags: python, qt, user-interface

I wrote a program that adds two numbers entered by the user into QLineEdit.
The result of the addition is output to the console in Pycharm.
How to make the result output to the application itself? (so that the user can see the answer).
I guess that there is some special method for this, but what is it?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Probnei(object):
def setupUi(self, Probnei):
    Probnei.setObjectName("Probnei")
    Probnei.resize(439, 309)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Probnei)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 140, 214, 22))
    self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
    self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
    self.Second_n = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
    self.Second_n.setObjectName("Second_n")
    self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Second_n)
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 210, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 60, 214, 22))
    self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
    self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
    self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
    self.First_n = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget)
    self.First_n.setObjectName("First_n")
    self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.First_n)
    Probnei.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(Probnei)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 439, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    Probnei.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(Probnei)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    Probnei.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(Probnei)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Probnei)

def retranslateUi(self, Probnei):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Probnei.setWindowTitle(_translate("Probnei", "MainWindow"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Probnei", "Второе число:"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Probnei", "Посчитать"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Probnei", "Первое число:"))
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.cal)

def cal(self, Probnei):
    val_1 = self.First_n.text()
    val_2 = self.Second_n.text()
    res = int(val_1) + int(val_2)
    print(res)
```

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Probnei = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Probnei()
    ui.setupUi(Probnei)
    Probnei.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: that method is to not use print but to either create or update a label with that value

Comment: Thank you. But how to do it? Cn you give me exemple, please?

Comment: no I can't I don't know much about Qt, simply look at the docs how to create some widget with text or how to configure it

Comment: You are right. But it's ussual not easy to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

> How to make the result output to the application itself?

It's not magic. You just have to create a widget that will display the answer. Then set the text on that widget when you do the calculation.

```
self.answerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)


def cal(self, Probnei):
    val_1 = self.First_n.text()
    val_2 = self.Second_n.text()
    res = int(val_1) + int(val_2)
    self.answerLabel.setText(res)
```